# Running two different Express servers but same passport sessions. Possible?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.socketio

I have two different express servers in one app. Both running socket.io server. I also using passport and mysql sessionStore.

I achieved successfully sharing passport login from express to socket.io **on one express server** by `passport.socketio` module.

Sadly this seems not working when I launch new express + socket.io server in same app and try to share passport login with this server running on different port.

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: does the web browser see these sites as the same site or is the user visiting different sites/ports?

Comment: @JimFactor Visiting different ports. But first server is used as website server + socket server and second server is used just as socket server for first website. So I am connecting to 2 sockets from 1 website